# rich:fileUpload fails to upload over HTTP/SSL w/ Apache2 + AJP + Tomcat 6.0.24

Tags: tomcat, ssl, richfaces

I'm currently unable to get `rich:fileUpload` working over HTTPS in Chrome 25 or IE 8.  The POST is sent, but never receives a response. Strangely, it *does* work over HTTPS in Firefox 19. It also works in all browsers when using HTTP.  Both HTTP and HTTPS requests are served through Apache httpd 2 to Tomcat 6.

When looking at a suspended HTTPS request thread, `org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest` keeps trying to read beyond the first byte, but never succeeds.  (See stack trace below.)

Does anyone have any suggestions, please?

Note: *not* using allowFlash (as in, it is set to false)

#### Versions in use:

- Richfaces 3.3.1
- Tomcat 6.0.24
- AJP 1.3
- Java 6
- Apache 2 running `mod_jk`

#### Stack trace from debugger:

> Daemon Thread [ajp-8009-5] (Suspended)
>       ByteArrayOutputStream.(int) line: 60
>       MultipartRequest.readHeader() line: 490 
>       MultipartRequest.readNext() line: 427
>       MultipartRequest.getParam(String) line: 807 
>       MultipartRequest.getParameter(String) line: 870 
>       IdentityRequestWrapper(ServletRequestWrapper).getParameter(String) line: 158
>       RequestParameterMap.getAttribute(String) line: 45
>       RequestParameterMap.getAttribute(String) line: 33
>       RequestParameterMap(AbstractAttributeMap).containsKey(Object) line: 59
>       HtmlResponseStateManager.isPostback(FacesContext) line: 212 
>       DefaultRestoreViewSupport.isPostback(FacesContext) line: 128
>       RestoreViewExecutor.execute(FacesContext) line: 80
>       LifecycleImpl.executePhase(FacesContext, PhaseExecutor, PhaseListenerManager) line: 103 
>       LifecycleImpl.execute(FacesContext) line: 76
>       FacesServlet.service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 151 
>       ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 290
>       ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
>       ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 190
>       ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235
>       ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
>       CurrentlySelectedTabFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 42
>       ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235
>       ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
>       PageLoadFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 58
>       ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235
>       ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
>       TimeoutFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 45
>       ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235
>       ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
>       ResourceTrackerFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 55
>       ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235
>       ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
>       SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 83
>       IdentityFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 40
>       SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 69
>       MultipartFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 90 
>       SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 69
>       ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 64 
>       SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 69
>       RedirectFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 45
>       SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 69
>       ConfigurableXMLFilter(BaseXMLFilter).doXmlFilter(FilterChain, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 178
>       Filter(BaseFilter).handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 290
>       Filter(BaseFilter).processUploadsAndHandleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 347
>       Filter(BaseFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 495 
>       Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 56
>       SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 69
>       SeamFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 158 
>       ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235
>       ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
>       CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 96 
>       CharacterEncodingFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 75
>       ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235
>       ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
>       StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 233
>       StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 191
>       BasicAuthenticator(AuthenticatorBase).invoke(Request, Response) line: 465
>       StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 127
>       ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 102
>       AccessLogValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 555
>       StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 109 
>       CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 298
>       AjpAprProcessor.process(long) line: 429 
>       AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(long) line: 384 
>       AprEndpoint$Worker.run() line: 1555 
>       Thread.run() line: 662

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using the "allowFlash" option but have the following bug on your radar.  We ran into it ourselves.
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-5624

Answer (score 0):

Try updating richfaces to 3.3.4 [(http://downloads.jboss.org/richfaces/releases/3.3.X/3.3.4.Final/richfaces-ui-3.3.4.Final-bin.zip)](http://downloads.jboss.org/richfaces/releases/3.3.X/3.3.4.Final/richfaces-ui-3.3.4.Final-bin.zip)

I had this problem in richfaces 3.3.1 with Jboss 5.1.0GA and Seam 2.2.0GA. Updated richfaces and now everything works as expected!

Hope it helps